# Grails + CAS + Web Services

Tags: web-services, authentication, grails, spring-security, cas

I've 3 grails applications using spring security. We use custom ahtentication providers for calling a web service and verify the users instead of a database.

Now we need to have a single sign on / out for those apps and we're looking the CAS alternative.

I read this blog post: http://blog.samimakela.fi/blog/2011/07/19/grails-and-single-sign-on/

But this approach uses a centralized text file for users/passwords.

- How can I configure my apps for using CAS and the web service?
- Do I need to configure a centralized user/password? (I know it sounds very rare, but y just wonder if I can authenticate in one app as always and with cas grant the access to other 2)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's pretty common to just use a shared database.

Comment: We can't use a shared user database. Everytime a user tries to log in we call a web service (provided by other company) and get the response with the data.